# Password protecting SQL database file

Tags: sql-server

I have created an SQL database file in Visual Studio for my ASP.NET MVC 3 project. How do i password protect my SQL database file?

Comment: Are you distributing this file? Who are you worried can gain access to it? You know that a SQL Server .mdf file is not something someone can just open with Excel, Access or Notepad and read, right?

Comment: I am using the database with a website i am hosting using IIS 8. I am trying to secure it against hackers, so they don't read the content of the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hackers can't get access to the file itself, if your host has any brains whatsoever.

And even if they could, they'd need some way to shut down SQL Server so they could obtain the file directly.

What you need to concern yourself with is:

- Setting up a very strong password for your web application user,
- giving the web user extremely limited rights (principle of least
  privilege),
- ensuring that the host places the database on a separate
  server that is protected from the outside world, and
- making sure your
  app isn't lazy about preventing SQL injection (e.g. use parameterized
  statements).